# Not a constant expression in lambda function

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-hana

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

#define HEADER_CONNECT 0b00010000
#define HEADER_CONNACK 0b00001000

struct ConnectFrame
{
    uint8_t header = 16;
    uint8_t variable = 2;
};

struct ConnackFrame
{
    uint8_t header = 8;
    uint8_t variable = 3;
};

constexpr auto FramesMap = hana::make_tuple(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnectFrame>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, HEADER_CONNECT>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnackFrame>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, HEADER_CONNACK>));

//! Runtime deserialization switch based on FramesMap
template <typename InputIterator>
auto deserializeByFrameHeader(const std::uint8_t frameHeader, const InputIterator buffer)
{
    auto found = hana::index_if(FramesMap, [&frameHeader = std::as_const(frameHeader)](auto const &pair) {
        return hana::second(pair) == hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, frameHeader>;
    });
    auto FrameType = hana::first(hana::at(FramesMap, found.value()));
    using T = typename decltype(FrameType)::type;
    T var;
    //deserialize(buffer, var);
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::byte, 128> buffer;
    // for dummy purposes we assume that the first byte of the buffer array after serialization is 8
    const uint8_t header = 8;
    ConnackFrame frameOut = deserializeByFrameHeader(header, buffer.begin());
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q2Z8MfCyHvFeqI12)

I try to find the index of the pair in the tuple which matches the variable frameHeader. Unfortunately, I get a compilation error:

```
../include/minimalMQTT.hpp:178:43: error: 'this' is not a constant expression
  178 |                 return hana::second(pair) == hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, frameHeader>;
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can the variable `frameHeader` be declared as a constant expression in order to make this work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried to provide a minimal working example, however it requires boost/hana to be available...

Comment: A function parameter is never `constexpr`, so `integral_c` cannot possibly work this way. You need to pass it as a template parameter to `deserializeByFrameHeader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, frameHeader>
```

`integral_c` is a type that encodes a statically known value. However you try to instantiate it with `frameHeader` which is not statically known.

To map runtime-values on compile-tume values the best you can do is a mapping (sometimes using binary search). However, you can also check whether you require this compiletime evaluated.

### Workaround

In your *specific* example you can work around things by using a constexpr lambda (given a recent enough compiler!).

In practice I doubt this would suit your needs, ever, but just so you're aware of the trick:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/brQ1XoAq2BzvCTzO)**

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/core/ignore_unused.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

#define HEADER_CONNECT 0b00010000
#define HEADER_CONNACK 0b00001000

struct ConnectFrame
{
    uint8_t header = 16;
    uint8_t variable = 2;
};

struct ConnackFrame
{
    uint8_t header = 8;
    uint8_t variable = 3;
};

constexpr auto FramesMap = hana::make_tuple(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnectFrame>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, HEADER_CONNECT>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnackFrame>, hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, HEADER_CONNACK>));

//! Runtime deserialization switch based on FramesMap
template <typename FrameHeader, typename InputIterator>
auto deserializeByFrameHeader(FrameHeader const frameHeader, const InputIterator buffer)
{
    auto found = hana::index_if(FramesMap, [=](auto const &pair) constexpr {
        return hana::second(pair) == hana::integral_c<std::uint8_t, frameHeader()>;
    });
    auto FrameType = hana::first(hana::at(FramesMap, found.value()));
    using T = typename decltype(FrameType)::type;
    T var;
    boost::ignore_unused(buffer);
    //deserialize(buffer, var);
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::byte, 128> buffer;
    // for dummy purposes we assume that the first byte of the buffer array after serialization is 8
    ConnackFrame frameOut = deserializeByFrameHeader(
            []() constexpr { return 8; },
            buffer.begin());

    boost::ignore_unused(frameOut);
}
```

### UPDATES

> Technically, the header is the first byte of the buffer array, i.e. uint8_t header = (uint8_t)buffer[0]. Would it be possible to omit the header argument and extract the header from the buffer as a constexpr directly?

No.

The return type is fixed. The input is dynamic. There's no way to pave over that (usefully/efficiently).

> By the way, what would be a solution if I don't need it compile time evaluated?

Since you're parsing protocol messages you're naturally switching on type ids (because that's how they exist on the wire). As a *serious C++ programmer* you naturally want to jump the abstraction layer to [proper type-switching](https://www.stroustrup.com/OOPSLA-typeswitch-draft.pdf) as soon as possible.

- The old-fashioned technique would be dynamic polymorphism (virtual interfaces and inheritance)
- Modern day mechanisms include `std::variant<...>` with visitation.

Depending on your usage patterns and processing needs either might be more applicable. `std::variant` has the nice feature that it encodes the type in a switchable manner, but visitation retains static type information. This means: technically you may be able to leverage static type information, inlining and all the optimization goodness.

It seems that **this is what you're after**. So I'd suggest:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6713df96b848fe3)**

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

constexpr uint8_t HEADER_CONNECT = 0b00010000;
constexpr uint8_t HEADER_CONNACK = 0b00001000;

struct ConnectFrame {
    uint8_t header = 16;
    uint8_t variable = 2;
};

struct ConnackFrame {
    uint8_t header = 8;
    uint8_t variable = 3;
};

// Static typed land
void handler(ConnectFrame const&) { std::cout << "Handling ConnectFrame\n"; }
void handler(ConnackFrame const&) { std::cout << "Handling ConnackFrame\n"; }

template <typename InputIterator>
void deserialize(InputIterator&, ConnectFrame&) { /*TODO*/ }

template <typename InputIterator>
void deserialize(InputIterator&, ConnackFrame&) { /*TODO*/ }

template <typename Frame, typename InputIterator>
Frame deserialize(InputIterator& buffer) {
    Frame frame;
    deserialize(buffer, frame);
    return frame;
}

// Type-swithcing land
template <typename InputIterator>
constexpr inline std::uint8_t frameHeader(InputIterator& buffer) {
    return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(*buffer++);
}

using AnyFrame = std::variant<ConnectFrame, ConnackFrame>;

template <typename InputIterator>
AnyFrame deserializeByFrameHeader(InputIterator&& buffer) {
    switch (uint8_t h = frameHeader(buffer)) {
        case HEADER_CONNECT: return deserialize<ConnectFrame>(buffer);
        case HEADER_CONNACK: return deserialize<ConnackFrame>(buffer);
    }
    throw std::range_error("frameHeader");
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto process = [](auto const& frame) { handler(frame); };
    using Buffer = std::array<std::byte, 128>;

    for (auto buffer : { Buffer 
        { std::byte(HEADER_CONNECT), std::byte(0x12), std::byte(0x34), },
        { std::byte(HEADER_CONNACK), std::byte(0xab), std::byte(0xcd), } })
    {
        auto frameOut = deserializeByFrameHeader(buffer.begin());
        std::visit(process, frameOut);
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
Handling ConnectFrame
Handling ConnackFrame
```

### Using the Hana Mapping

If you really think it's important to work from the mappings table, you can, using a bit more code and compiler sweat:

```
constexpr auto FramesMap = hana::make_tuple(
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnectFrame>, HEADER_CONNECT),
    hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnackFrame>, HEADER_CONNACK)
);
```

> Note how I dropped the `integral_c` because we don't need it

Let's make `AnyFrame` a variant over the frame-types:

```
constexpr auto FrameTypes = hana::transform(FramesMap, hana::first);

using AnyFrame = decltype(
        hana::unpack(FrameTypes, hana::template_<std::variant>))
    ::type;
```

Now, let's reimplement `deserializeByFrameHeader` using it:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
AnyFrame deserializeByFrameHeader(InputIterator&& buffer) {
    AnyFrame retval;

    hana::for_each(FramesMap,
        [&, frameHeader = frameHeader(buffer)](auto const &pair) {
            auto first = hana::first(pair);
            using T = typename decltype(first)::type;

            if (hana::second(pair) == frameHeader) {
                retval.emplace<T>();
                deserialize(buffer, std::get<T>(retval));
            }
        });

    return retval;
}
```

Note the the simplification: we kept everything depending on the static type of the tuple element (`pair`) inside the polymorphic lambda, where we have the frametype available at all times.

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/037240edb3abb57f)**

```
#include <cstdint>
constexpr uint8_t HEADER_CONNECT = 0b00010000;
constexpr uint8_t HEADER_CONNACK = 0b00001000;

struct ConnectFrame {
    uint8_t header = 16;
    uint8_t variable = 2;
};

struct ConnackFrame {
    uint8_t header = 8;
    uint8_t variable = 3;
};

#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    namespace hana = boost::hana;

    constexpr auto FramesMap = hana::make_tuple(
        hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnectFrame>, HEADER_CONNECT),
        hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<ConnackFrame>, HEADER_CONNACK)
    );

    constexpr auto FrameTypes = hana::transform(FramesMap, hana::first);

    using AnyFrame = decltype(
            hana::unpack(FrameTypes, hana::template_<std::variant>))
        ::type;
}

// Static typed land
void handler(ConnectFrame const&) { std::cout << "Handling ConnectFrame\n"; }
void handler(ConnackFrame const&) { std::cout << "Handling ConnackFrame\n"; }

template <typename InputIterator>
void deserialize(InputIterator&, ConnectFrame&) { /*TODO*/ }

template <typename InputIterator>
void deserialize(InputIterator&, ConnackFrame&) { /*TODO*/ }

// Type-swithcing land
template <typename InputIterator>
constexpr inline std::uint8_t frameHeader(InputIterator& buffer) {
    return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(*buffer++);
}

template <typename InputIterator>
AnyFrame deserializeByFrameHeader(InputIterator&& buffer) {
    AnyFrame retval;

    hana::for_each(FramesMap,
        [&, frameHeader = frameHeader(buffer)](auto const &pair) {
            auto first = hana::first(pair);
            using T = typename decltype(first)::type;

            if (hana::second(pair) == frameHeader) {
                retval.emplace<T>();
                deserialize(buffer, std::get<T>(retval));
            }
        });

    return retval;
}

#include <array>
int main() {
    constexpr auto process = [](auto const& frame) { handler(frame); };
    using Buffer = std::array<std::byte, 128>;

    for (auto buffer : { Buffer 
        { std::byte(HEADER_CONNECT), std::byte(0x12), std::byte(0x34), },
        { std::byte(HEADER_CONNACK), std::byte(0xab), std::byte(0xcd), } })
    {
        auto frameOut = deserializeByFrameHeader(buffer.begin());
        std::visit(process, frameOut);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Handling ConnectFrame
Handling ConnackFrame
```

Comment: Taking a page from Pure Functional dogma: everything is a function works https://wandbox.org/permlink/brQ1XoAq2BzvCTzO if you have constexpr lambdas

Comment: Technically, the header is the first byte of the buffer array, i.e.  ```uint8_t header = (uint8_t)buffer[0]```. Would it be possible to omit the header argument and extract the header from the buffer as a constexpr directly?

Comment: By the way, what would be a solution if I don't need it compile time evaluated?

Comment: @P.Zeugin I learned myself some more Hana to come up with good answers to these. See the **UPDATE** sections (one implementation without Hana, one with). Cheers